# embedded font looks diffrent from source sample

Tags: html, css, fonts

I downloaded this font called [Bender](https://fonts2u.com/bender-italic.font) and embedded it on my website like this:

```
@font-face { font-family: Bender-Italic; src: url('files/Bender.otf'); } 
@font-face { font-family: Bender-Italic; font-weight: normal; src:  
url('files/Bender.otf');}
body
{
font-family: Bender, sans-serif;
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;
}
```

but in the browser it doesn't display like in the sample. If I don't choose this font in body sections, different font shows so it definitely does something.

I have tried this [fix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1923338/embedded-font-looks-different-than-supposed-to) yet it didn't help(ofcourse I used modern syntax, not fontWeight etc).

One possible cause could be that my doctype is

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
```

instead of

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.1 Transitional//EN">
```

but when I change it the size of the font and some other formatting doesn't want to work properly etc so I would rather keep it.
[Here is the website](https://kwandesisamazing.000webhostapp.com/) so you can see what 'broken' font looks like. Also google fonts etc all work fine.

Comment: I only see the 'Fontello' file and 'Asar' font appear in your 'files' folder, are you sure you put these in the correct place?

Comment: Ah forgot the update the online website. Will do that in couple of hours when I finish some stuff

Comment: Ehm, there is no version 4.1 of HTML. What's wrong with just using the HTML5 doctype?